# How to check the checkbox when in_array is true

Tags: php, checkbox

I need to check the checkbox when the `in_array` function is true. The looping going fine but it checks all checkboxes whether the bool is true or false.

**$pixArr**

```
Array(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [imgFile] => IMG_7516.JPG
            [imgTime] => 11:39
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [imgFile] => IMG_7515.JPG
            [imgTime] => 11:39
        )

)
```

**$dTime**

```
Array(
    [0] => 11-26-50
    [1] => 11-26-50
    [2] => 11-39-43
    [3] => 11-39-43
    [4] => 14-35-38
)
```

**$fTime**=11-26-50

```
foreach($pixArr as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($fTime,$dTime)){
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\" checked/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }else{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\"/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }
}
```

I expect the input which time `11-26-50` is checked. Because is turns out the `in_array` true. But it checks every input in the loop. I don't understand why.

Comment: This is because the value is in the array everytime, regardless of what we are looping over

Comment: codeHeart is right. you iterate over $pixArr, but only check $fTime and $dTime, which do not change. i guess you'd have to check $val['imgTime'] instead? but there you have to adjust the used time format

Comment: I think it would be easier to give an answer if you give a little background about the problem, right now we don't have an idea of what is dtime or ftime and what do you want to achieve. As Mentioned by Franz, that too can be a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to check as problem described by you

```
foreach($dTime as $key=>$val)
{    
    if($fTime == $val)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\" checked/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\"/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare 'time' values as strings they should be brought into the same format:

```
$dTime = [
    0 => '11-26-50',
    1 => '11-26-50',
    2 => '11-39-43',
    3 => '11-39-43',
    4 => '14-35-38'
];

$dTimeFormatted = array_map(function($v){
    return substr(str_replace("-",":",$v), 0, 5);
}, $dTime); 

foreach ($pixArr as $key => $val) {
    $inTime = in_array($val['imgTime'], $dTimeFormatted);        
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"{$val['imgFile']}\" ".(($inTime)? '"checked"':" " )."/>&nbsp;Select</label>";        
}
```

Comment: This is the new trick of replace a string in array (of me). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$fTime` within your foreach-loop. If not, you're just going to loop through the full `$pixArr` since `in_array($fTime,$dTime)` is `true` all the time.

```
foreach($pixArr as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($fTime,$dTime)){
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\" checked/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }else{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\"/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
    }
    $fTime = //update fTime here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew now. Because the compare value in `in_array` is nothing to do with the loop. I cannot compare `$fTime` with `$dTime`. I have to compare the `$val[imgTime]` with `$dTime` **in the same format**.

Here is the point.
Now **$dTime** format is `HH-mm-ss` while **$val[imgTime]** is `HH:mm:ss`.

I have to change them into the same format. So I decided to change **$val[imgTime]**.

```
$vTime=str_replace(":","-",$val['imgTime']);
```

So, the final script is:

```
foreach($pixArr as $key=>$val){
$vTime=str_replace(":","-",$val['imgTime']);
if(in_array($vTime,$dTime)){
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\" checked/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
}else{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"file[]\" value=\"$val[imgFile]\"/>&nbsp;Select</label>";
}
```

Thanks for the clues from @codeHeart, @frank and every answers.